# SIGALRM waits for subshell processes?

Tags: shell, signals

Here is the unexpected situation: in the following script, `SIGALRM` doesn't invoke the function `alarm()` at the expected time.

```
#!/bin/sh -x

alarm() {
  echo "alarmed!!!"
}

trap alarm 14
OUTER=$(exec sh -c 'echo $PPID')

#for arg in `ls $0`; do
ls $0 | while read arg; do
  INNER=$(exec sh -c 'echo $PPID')

  # child A, the timer
  sleep 1 && kill -s 14 $$ &

  # child B, some other scripts
  sleep 60 &

  wait $!
done
```

**Expectation**:
 After 1 second, the function `alarm()` should be called.

**Actually**:
 `alarm()` is called until 60s, or when we hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

We know in the script, `$$` actually indicates the `OUTER` process, so I suppose we should see the string printed to screen after 1 second. However, it is until child B exits do we see `alarm()` is called.

When we get the `trap` line commented, the whole program just terminates after 1 second. So... I suppose `SIGALRM` is at least received, but why doesn't it invoke actions?

And, as a side question, is the default behavior of `SIGALRM` to be termination? From [here](http://ocamlunix.forge.ocamlcore.org/signals.html) I am told that by default it is ignored, so why `OUTER` exits after receiving it?

Comment: What's your actual goal with this program?

Comment: @JohnZwinck my actual goal is to create two child processes and control each other: the first child will send SIGALARM to main process to kill second child, if the latter is timed out; the second one will kill the first child, if the former simply exits. I have completed the goal actually, but here I'm trying to reproduce an unexpected situation during my tests.

Comment: I see you have `sleep 60 &` .. how do u know this is not sleeping this process?

Comment: @Bill sorry but we have actually 4 processes here, so what do you mean by **this**?

Comment: i mean when you have `sleep 60 &` the current process (i.e. your shell script) will sleep for 60 secs. I am not sure how you are saying that the sleep will actually make `some other script` go to sleep.

Comment: @billybob I see you have 2 `exec sh...`, so total 3 processes, one main shell and 2 child. Where is the 4th process? Jst making sure I understand this correctly.

Comment: @Bill Oh, you should note that the pipeline creates two subprocess... So it is actually 5...(the script is grandfather, the pipeline(ls & while read) occupies two, and two children created by the subshell(while read))

Comment: run a `ps` after running your script in the background. You have `3 sh` processes and `2 sleep` processes, as expected. The piping and while are internal and should not spawn a new process (AFAIK). I changed the `sleep 60` to `sleep 10` and alarm was after 10secs. So your `sleep 60` is causing the main process to go to sleep.

Comment: @Bill Sorry I cannot explain why `ps` works like that, maybe it just prints out **active** process. But we **really** have at least 5 processes, you can see that the variables `OUTER` and `INNER` shows different result. I hope someone can explain this to both us :)

Comment: ok, may be this will help. I was wrong, `while` indeed spawns a new process. The value of OUTER is the pid of your script. The PPID of INNER is the pid of the process due to while loop. Run `ps` and verify. But, your `exec..` will die pretty soon. So you are left with 3 `sh` processes and 2 `sleep` processes as they are running in background.

Comment: @Bill Oh, still, don't ignore that `ls` process. Actually I suspect this weird situation relates to pipeline -- if you get the while loop replaced by for loop, things go as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `bash` man page:

*If bash is waiting for a command to complete and receives a signal for which a trap has been set,  the  trap  will
       not  be  executed  until  the  command  completes.   When bash is waiting for an asynchronous command via the wait
       builtin, the reception of a signal for which a trap has been set will cause the wait builtin to return immediately
       with an exit status greater than 128, immediately after which the trap is executed.*

Your original script is in the first scenario.  The subshell (the while read loop) has called `wait`, but the top level script is just waiting for the subshell, so when it receives the signal, the trap is not executed until the subshell completes.  If you send the signal to the subshell with `kill -s 14 $INNER`, you get the behavior you expect.

Comment: Interesting! So it is `wait` that does the evil thing? Hmm, when I replace the while loop by for loop (comment in the codes), I suppose the parent shell should also be blocked by `wait` and ignore alarm signal? Why things go as expected at this time?

Comment: When you use a for loop (I assume you mean `for x in $0;...`), the parent (ie, the shell that receives the signal) is invoking `wait`, so the second sentence applies and `wait` returns immediately.